# Java referencing an out-a-scope object

Tags: java, garbage-collection, strong-references

I'm saving the previous value of a Java object.  I (almost) understand references are strong, weak, etc. but I can't find an example that classifies my specific situation that is apparently referencing an out-of-scope object. (I've looked at a lot of posts on this subject.)

Is the Java reference `aTestCopy` to the out-of-scope array of objects `aTest` valid?

It's a shallow copy but is it subject to garbage collection thus I need a deep copy for it to work reliably every time? Or should the declaration of the new object `aTest` be placed outside the `while` with the "previous" copied object `aTestCopy`?

Is the use of a `null` a good practice for the first-time-through switch or should that be a separate `boolean` variable?
Thanks.

```
Tester[] aTestCopy = null;
while(true)
{
    Tester[] aTest = myMethodReturnsATesterArray(); // new values

    // need code to skip using aTestCopy the first time through - no previous value
    // else use the previous value here

    aTestCopy = aTest; // save them for the next use of previous values
}
```

Comment: Scope is a compile time concept. It applies to the use of names in the program code. `aTest` is one such name, in this case a variable. At runtime, `aTest` contains a reference to an object. When `aTestCopy = aTest` runs, the value of the reference gets copied from `aTest` into `aTestCopy`.

Comment: The term “out of scope” makes no sense for objects. Only *variables* have scope, which tells whether the name is valid. Objects have *reachability*. If you [can] access an object through a variable (any will do), it’s reachable.

Comment: Regarding your other question, initializing a variable with `null` is not a good practice, but unavoidable in scenarios like this. Using a `boolean` variable wouldn’t help as the compiler would still complain if you don’t initialize the variable.

Comment: I'm wondering about this: `It's a shallow copy`. I read this as that you expect the assignment `aTestCopy = aTest;` to create a copy. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem to use `null` as initial value for reference types in Java. But there isn't any relevance between initialize a reference type as `null` and garbage collection. You should initialize `aTestCopy` as null to use in another scope like in your case in `while`.

Garbage collection is triggered whenever an object in memory is not pointed anymore by any reference.

When you assign a reference type to another reference type (if it is not immutable in this case), you made copy the memory address of that value. So when you can make a change in `aTestCopy` will be reflected to the reference `aTest`.

Comment: `Garbage collection is triggered whenever an object in memory is not pointed anymore by any reference.` This is not correct. There are lot's of possible reasons for a gc but this is not one. However, the object will collected during a gc if it's not reachable

Comment: I think we can't say **this is not correct** strictly. We can say, this is not the only reason. Because it is well-known mark and sweep algorithm that is used in garbage collection mechanisms.

Comment: Err, I do think we can. There _might_ be some very specific edge cases where this could happen but in the vast vast majority of cases this is not true. It also doesn't matter what actual gc algorithm is used.

Comment: I'm btw well aware of how a mark-sweep gc works.

Comment: The statement “*Garbage collection is triggered whenever an object in memory is not pointed anymore by any reference*” is definitely wrong, regardless of the implementation, because it reverses cause and effect. Before the garbage collection, the JVM doesn’t know whether there are references to an object because that’s precisely what garbage collection will find out. So this information can’t be the trigger for the garbage collection. It’s the result.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, variables do not hold objects, only references to objects.

The lifetime of objects is largely independent of the lifetime of variables: Objects are created by executing `new`, and reclaimed once the program has relinquished all means of accessing them (i.e. the object is no longer reachable form the references the program holds).

Put differently, the first variable to hold a reference to an object holds no special significance. In particular, it does not determine the lifetime of that object. *Any* reference will keep the object alive, and there can be no such thing as an "out of scope" object.

Similarly, when you assign a variable of reference type, you are only assigning the reference, causing both variables to point to the same object, and to see any changes done to this object though the other variable.

If you want a new object, you must use `new` (or call a method that uses `new`).

In your case, I'd make sure that `myMethodReturnsATesterArray` returns a `new` array, referencing `new` Tester objects. Then, the objects created by separate iterations of the loop will exist independently, allowing the loop to reference both the old and new objects and do whichever comparision it deems appropriate, without having to fear that the invocation of `myMethodReturnsATesterArray` has somehow changed the previous object.